# Using negative lookbehind and lookahead in html5 pattern

Tags: regex, html, regex-lookarounds

I have tried looking over quite a lot of regex guides on how to use the negative lookbehind and lookahead in my regex function for html5 pattern.

I am trying to match the following pattern, where the string has to start and end with a `[a-z]` letter. The string can be up to 30 characters long. Can also include the symbol: `-`, however it can never have more than one `-` in a row.

Sooo, what I came up with so far is this:

```
^[a-z][a-z(?<!-(-)?!-)]{0,28}[a-z]$
```

Now I could not get the lookahead and lookbehind so work properly and I am not quite sure if I implemented the max 30 characters correctly. However, I have tried starting and ending with `[a-z]` and it works fine.

Some example strings:

```
'a-b' => true
'a-' => false
'-a' => false
'a--b' => false
'ab-cd' => true
'abc' => true
'a-b-c' => true
```

Comment: Try `^(?!.{31})[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$`. It is not clear if you only want to match strings like `abc-xyz-def` and `aaaaaa`, or if `a-()*^a` are also valid. Please add some examples of strings you allow and some you do not allow.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sweet, seemes like its working, could you explain the structure you used? It seemes so off from what I used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew See update for some examples of allowed strings.

Comment: I added an answer with a demo and explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use

```
^(?!.{31})[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWVYBR/2)

Note that in an HTML5 *pattern* attribute, the anchors are usually not required as the pattern is anchored on both sides by default.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.{31})` - there cannot be 31 chars other than line break chars (this `(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern is matched) (you may also use a positive lookahead - `(?=.{1,30}$)` - that requires 1 to 30 chars in the string)
- `[a-z]+` - 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:-[a-z]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `[a-z]+` - 1 or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Do you have time to explain the function of `?:` in the zero or more sequences of section?

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471) It is used for grouping purposes when we do not need to access the submatch value. E.g. Casimir's pattern can be written as `^(?:[a-z]|\b-\b){1,30}$`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look on the link you provided :)

Comment: You may also [see how the HTML5 regex patterns are handled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-pattern-attribute): *the `pattern` attribute is matched against the entire value, not just any subset (somewhat as if it implied a `^(?:` at the start of the pattern and a `)$` at the end)*

Answer (score 3):

You can use this pattern:

```
([a-z]|\b-\b){1,30}
```

The word boundaries prevent hyphens to be consecutive or to be at the string limits.

Note that `^` and `$` are not needed in the pattern attribute since they are implicit.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/H3bufI/1/)

Comment: There are frameworks that override the regular HTML5 pattern behavior, so it might be a good idea to keep the anchors where they should be.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the question is about html5, not about any framework. If a framework isn't able to anchor the pattern itself, it should not be used.

Comment: I was not aware that HTML5 included these anchors, what are the reason for NOT including these in every case?

Comment: @PhyCoMath: As I said before the anchors are implicit. The reason is probably that the pattern is supposed to describe a whole string and not only a part of this string. Whatever, even if you only want a condition for a part of the string, you can build a pattern describing a whole string with this condition; but you can't always build a simple condition to describe a whole string. (perhaps this fact explains this choice).

Comment: This is a _5 star_ answer. +1